# Search Confluence Cloud content via REST API by label and expand metadata

Tags: confluence, confluence-rest-api

The goal is to retrieve from Confluence Cloud all the pages containing label `some-label`.

When searching Confluence using `cql` the query does return result set but does not include `metadata` (specifically `labels`), though `expand` key is explicitly passed to the query:

`https://foobar.atlassian.net/wiki/rest/api/search/?expand=metadata.labels&cql=type=page&label="some-label"`

What is the reason for `expand` being neglected? Or is the query itself misconfigured?

---

I used Confluence [Search API Reference](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/confluence/rest/api-group-search/#api-api-search-get)

Answer (score -1):

Having trying to solve the same issue for while. It's simply a different method.

GET `/wiki/rest/api/search` does not support expansion, although the parameter is listed in the documentation

GET `/wiki/rest/api/content/search` does support expansion.

The confluence documentation for the latter includes all properties which can be expanded.
https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/confluence/rest/api-group-content/#api-wiki-rest-api-content-search-get

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, in order for the next user to understand your answer better. Also, provide a basic coverage of the content of your link, in case it stops working in the future.